# Is there a way to find out which process is writing to a specific disk

Tags: linux, process, io

Right now I can use `dstat` to find out the I/O status of individual disks, and `iotop` to find out the I/O status of individual processes, but I can't find a tool that can combine these two functions. I tried to compare the timestamps of these two records, but they don't seem to correspond. It would be great if there is a way to show which process is writing to a specific disk, so I can finally find out what process is intermittently writing to my storage disk.

Comment: Would `blktrace` work for you?

Comment: check `lsof +D`